# Flags Stack Distance Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am plotting flags in HighStock charts .
Its a multiple series chart.
I am plotting the flags like {x:21,y:32} .
But my flags get overlapped .And stack distance is also not working.

```
[
                              {
                                 name : 'X Series',
                                 id : 'series1',
                                 data : data1,
                                 allowPointSelect : true,
                                 color : '#840000'
                              },
                              {
                                 name : 'Y Series',
                                 data : data2,
                                 dashStyle : 'shortdot',
                                 id : 'series2',
                                 color : '#840000',
                                 allowPointSelect : true
                              },
                              {
                                 type : 'flags',
                                 data : myflagsData,
                                 stackDistance : 20,
                                 shape : 'square',
                                 color : '#000000',
                                 //width : 5,
                                 showInLegend : false                                 
                              } 
                           ]
```

More info  here :-
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/7303396-prevent-flags-overlap

http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/flags-stack-distance-not-working-t32157/

Comment: Any updates guys .Can anyone help me with this. Check out sample here : 
[link](http://codepen.io/niketh90/pen/BNdYZW)
And Click ALL option

Answer (score 1):

You need to define stackDistance, like in the example:

```
plotOptions:{
            series:{
                stackDistance: 20
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fq2uo1o5/1/

Comment: This will work only if the X Axis data is same .If close Values of y corresponding to close values of X this wont work .

Stack Distance only works when the plot is on same point .But in my case there are around 1000plotting points and flags become close and overlap. The flags are not on same point .Any workaround for this.

Comment: Please update my code with your data to introduce that issue.

Comment: Sorry friend. Jsfiddle has been blocked recently in my organization so cant test it . Consider having 2000 points in your chart .
consider X Axis is 3 years .So this graph is plotting 3 Years data .
if For a date 12March 2012 and 13 March 2012 there is a flag with Y axis value same  .This flag will overlap each other. 

I Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use jsbin or other online tools to show us your scenario.

Comment: Hi ,Managed to get it on codepen .After loading please click All in the chart .Please see

[link](http://codepen.io/niketh90/pen/BNdYZW)

Comment: The problem is that stackDistance works, when flags has the same x, in your case you have differect value so it is a reason of that. Unfortunately at this moment we have no "anti-collisiton" module, which will fix this issue. But you can post your suggestion in our uservoice [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

Comment: Yes i have raised the issue [link](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/7303396-prevent-flags-overlap)

If anyone else can help ,please comment.

Comment: Any anticollision algorithm going to be introduced soon ? Any Idea people ?